# work on distinct elements of RDD-pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming, rdd

I am receiving data from Kafka into a Spark Streaming application. It comes in the format of Transformed DStreams. I then keep only the features i want.
`features=data.map(featurize)`
which gives me the *"name","age","whatever"*.
I then want to keep only the *name* of all the data
`features=data.map(featurize).map(lambda Names: Names["name"]`

Now, when i print this command, i get all the names coming from the streaming application, but i want to work on each one separately.
More specifically, I want to check each name and if I have already came across it in the past i want to apply a function on it. Otherwise i will just continue with my application. So I want each name to be a string so that I can insert it into my function that checks if one string has been seen in the past.

I know that `foreach` will give me each RDD , but still I want to work on each name of the RDDs separately.

Is there any way in pyspark to do so?

Comment: Did you try updateStateByKey, where the keys are your names?

Comment: how can i use updateStateByKey to keep the names from different streaming windows?

Comment: You can find useful information here (Find the updateStateByKey section): http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

So what i did was to define a function that checks if I have seen that name in the past and then use the `.filter(myfunc)` to only work with the names i want...

The problem now is that in each new streaming window the function is being applied from the beggining , so if i have seen the name John in the first window 7 times , i will keep it only once , but then if i have seen the name John in the second window 5 times i will keep it again once...

I want to keep the name John once for all the streaming application...
Any thoughts on that ?